# JsfExceptionHandler ConstraintViolationImp messageTemplate

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, exceção

Tenho o mapeamento na classe usuário:

```
@NotNull(message = "Contato não pode ser vázio.")
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "contact_id")
@Getter
@Setter
private Contato contato;
```

O qual tenho a classe `JsfExceptionHandler` que captura todas as exceções da aplicação. Efetuei o tratamento para erros de `constraint violations`, porém preciso que seja exibido somente a mensagem da validação e não todo o texto do erro como esta acontecendo.

Mensagem que esta sendo exibida:

```
Validation failed for classes 
[br.com.openfiscal.model.Usuario] during persist time for groups 
[javax.validation.groups.Default, ] 
List of constraint violations: 
    [ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Contato não pode ser vázio.', 
    propertyPath=contato, rootBeanClass=class br.com.openfiscal.model.Usuario, 
    messageTemplate='Contato não pode ser vázio.'} ]
```

Desejo exibir somente o `messageTemplate`.